# Updating lightning web component on record update

Tags: lightning-web-components, refresh, refreshapex

I have a lightning web component added to a custom object's lightning record page.That lightning record page also has standard record detail as one of the components.Whenever record is updated using this standard detail page,I need to refresh my lightning web component(similar to lightning data service).I couldnt implement lightning data service for my functionality.

Is it possible to listen to record update through salesforce events?If so,which model should I use - Pushtopics,Platform events,Change Data Capture.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Just curious...why is data service not an option?

Comment: In my requirement, query is formed dynamically based on fields(it can be any field and any object) given in the design attributes of lwc and records are fetched based on that and displayed.So if particular fields are updated in record detail page,I have to refresh the component or reload the entire page and need to display the updated values.